# What is the name of the bug that emerging from a wood chip like cocoon?

Tags: species-identification, species, invasive-species

We found it on the wall of a home at West Palm Beach Florida. Is this a kind of infestation or a sick tree near the house fall on the wall?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a bagworm moth, in the family Psychidae. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagworm_moth